# PHP as daemon/service

Tags: php, linux, daemon

can i achieve this with php (LINUX machine):

i have php binary already running, and then feed it with php script file to be executed. So it's basically something like,

`php myscript.php`

but what i need is, the `myscript.php` is given later to php binary (cli), anyone know how to achieve this? what i need is (maybe something like), write something to php process INPUT and take the result from its output.

Any suggestion please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you actually want to achieve, in which setting, or what the problem is. Invoking the script works exactly as you already mentioned. Sending input and reading its output works with [`pipes`](http://www.google.com/search?q=unix+shell+pipes).

```
cat input.txt | php-cli myscript.php | tee write-output-here.txt
```

And to read input or write output in PHP use the magic [`php://stdin`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) or [`php://stdout`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) filenames.

That's basically how you can register a script as inetd handler, where it would receive network input and can send its output as result back.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention. I will supply the "input" to the running php-cli from c++. I'm trying to avoid the need of "starting up" php, by make it already running, and then feed the script that need to be executed, and of course, get the result/output of that script. So i don't want to execute "php myscript.php" everytime, but the "php" is already running, and i will ask it to "execute this script please..."

Comment: You could interface to the FastCGI daemon. There's a library for C++ too. But that's kind of cumbersome. So, I would go the daemon route. Extend the myscript.php with [PEAR::Net_Server](http://pear.php.net/Net_Server).