# C++ popen to run PHP

Tags: php, c++, linux, command-line-interface, popen

i'm using popenRWE from http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/popenRWE and making the script below

```
int pipes[3];
int pid;
const char *const args[] = {
    "php ",
    NULL
};
pid = popenRWE(pipes, args[0], args); 

char *cmd = "<?php echo 'hello world';?> ";
cout << "write: " << write(pipes[0], cmd, strlen(cmd)) << endl;
cout << "err: " << errno << endl;

char res[100];
cout << "read: " << read(pipes[1], res, 100) << endl;
cout << "result: " << res << endl;
```

when i use `cat` command, it works, the input is the ouput (that's what cat doing), but using `php` the read is empty. i have confirmed that php is installed and on my path by running

`echo "<?php echo 'hello world';?>" | php`

directly on the console, and got the output. Can someone please advise or help on this code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `popenRWE` return a valid id (i.e. not an error)? Is `php` in the `$PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

- There is no executable named `"php "`. There is just `"php"` (notice that there is no space). The reason why this does not work is beceause `popenRWE` uses [`execvp`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execvp.htm) which does not start a shell to execute the command but it expects the filename of the binary you want to executed (it searches for it in `$PATH` though).
- You should `close` the `stdin`-filehandle after you've written your data, otherwise you might have to wait indefinitely for the output to be written.
- Also you should wait for the `php`-process to finish using `waitpid` because otherwise you might "lose" some of the output.

To wrap it up:

```
int pipes[3];
int pid;
const char *const args[] = {
    "php",
    NULL
};
pid = popenRWE(pipes, args[0], args);

char *cmd = "<?php echo 'hello world', \"\\n\";?> ";
cout << "write: " << write(pipes[0], cmd, strlen(cmd)) << endl;
cout << "err: " << errno << endl;
close(pipes[0]);

// TODO: proper error handling
int status;
waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

char res[100];
int bytesRead = read(pipes[1], res, (sizeof(res)/sizeof(char))-1);
// zero terminate the string
res[bytesRead >= 0 ? bytesRead : 0] = '\0';

cout << "read: " << bytesRead << endl;
cout << "result: " << res << endl;
```

Comment: so that means i cannot reuse the `stdin`-filehandle since it is closed right after the writing. any chance to keep it open and reusing it? i'm trying to achieve something as i described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844320/php-as-daemon-service where the php process is already opened, and i simply feed the script to the process handler to get its output.

Comment: You have a segmentation fault when bytesRead = 100 when you zero terminate the string

Comment: @user777305: you can flush it instead of closing.

Comment: @Dani can you please provide a sample code on flushing, or the function name? i'm weak on c stuff. thanks.

Comment: @user777305: `flush(pipes[0])` instead of close.

Comment: @Dani i tried that before and get `error: no matching function for call to âflush(int&)â`, included fstream

Comment: @Dani: segfault fixed - thank you. @user777305: Just replace `close` with `fsync` (which is what flush does) and remove the `waitpid`-part. But it won't work since PHP reads until `EOF`. You have to create a PHP-script which just reads a line and executes it, that might work with "flushing".

Comment: @vstm thanks for your answer. it works though i still cannot make the `pipes[0]` reusable. about the segfaults, any suggestion on how determine the number 100 ? since i don't really know how much space will be needed, i need something that can dynamically fit to the php output size.